# What does the phrase 'by lack of' in this context refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the "by lack of" here grammatically correct? Here is the whole context, with emphasis added.

> ### 6. Function fields
>
> I will only say a very few words about the "geometric" analogue (or "function field case") of the various theories described before, mostly **by lack of** proper competence. More detailed explanations will come in future chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[for lack of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20lack%20of) appears to be the more idiomatic construction.

Anyway

“By lack of” ,conveys the same meaning.